# Nuxtjs i18n custom locale

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, nuxtjs, nuxt-i18n

I have an application, the main problem is that i can't understand how to "create" custom locale. For example i have routes like this `/hello` and `/ja/hello`, where the first route is default english language and the second one is japanese. I trying to left my english locale without prefix, but add the prefix only for one route of this version like `/eng/hello`.

My nuxt.config.js for i18n:

```
i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        file: 'en.js',
        domain: domains.en,
        icon: 'english',
        name: 'English',
        iso: 'en',
      },
      {
        code: 'ja',
        file: 'ja.js',
        domain: domains.ja,
        icon: 'japan',
        name: '日本語',
        iso: 'ja',
      },
    ],
    // differentDomains: true,
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'lang/',
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      cookieKey: 'clang',
      onlyOnRoot: true, // recommended
      alwaysRedirect: true,
    },
    seo: false,
    strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring under the modules prop like this, example from my project:

```
  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    'nuxt-socket-io',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    ['nuxt-i18n', {
      locales: [
        {
          name: 'Türkçe',
          code: 'tr',
          iso: 'tr-TR',
          file: 'tr-TR.js'
        },
        {
          name: 'English',
          code: 'en',
          iso: 'en-US',
          file: 'en-US.js'
        },
      ],
      langDir: 'lang/',
      defaultLocale: 'en',
    }]
  ],

  i18n: {},
```